Play Console accessibility warning android:id/content/s[1] - Flutter App
The problem I have is that when I upload an app to the play console, in the previous report, I always have the accessibility warning that covers the entire screen. This happens with all my apps, even with the one that is generated as an example. I have already added several Semantics() tags but it doesn't solve. I have even tried showing only a blank screen as seen in the image.
At least, I would like to know if anyone who got this error has managed to publish their app or it has been rejected.

This is the code I used for that screen
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:planificat2/services/app_version_info_service.dart';
import 'package:planificat2/services/firebase_remote_config_service.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

import 'package:planificat2/share_prefs/preferecias_usuario.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

//////////CRASHLYTICS
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
  };
  // Pass all uncaught asynchronous errors that aren't handled by the Flutter framework to Crashlytics
  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
    return true;
  };


  final prefs = Preferenciasusuario();
  await prefs.initPrefs();


  final remoteConfigService = FirebaseRemoteConfigService();
  await remoteConfigService.initialize();




  await AppVersionPackageInfo().initialize();
  runApp(Semantics(label: "Test", child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Semantics(
        label: "PlanificAT",
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Semantics(label: "Test", child: const SizedBox()),
        ));
  }
}


